# page object model with drop down menu c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've written a selenium test which i'm now moving to page object model.

I understand how XPaths work for page object model

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "article img")]
private IWebElement clickItem;
```

But i now have a drop down menu which want to also make page object model. How would i go about doing this.

```
  private static void SelectElementFromDropDown(IWebElement ele, string text)
  {
      SelectElement select = new SelectElement(ele);
      select.SelectByText(text);

      IWebElement Size = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//select[@data-id='sizeSelect']"));
      SelectElementFromDropDown(Size, "UK 10 - EU 45 - US 11");
  }
```

Comment: share your html code please?

Comment: Please see update

Comment: same way you can add the select tag element to page object and try to use it in your code.

Comment: How would this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can the element to page factory like,

```
Class Page{

private IWebDriver driver;

[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "select[data-id='sizeSelect']")]
private IWebElement listBox;

}
```

Then call in the test as given below.

```
private static void SelectElementFromDropDown(IWebElement ele, string text)
{
      SelectElement select = new SelectElement(ele);
      select.SelectByText(text);

}
```

From Test you can call,

```
var page = new Page();
PageFactory.InitElements(driver, page);
SelectElementFromDropDown(page.listBox, "UK 10 - EU 45 - US 11");
```